# how to delete a button run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a problem in my C# winform project.
In my project I have function that make a new button at runtime. Because sometimes I make too many buttons I want to write a function that deletes the button that I want to delete at run time.
Someone maybe have already that function?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button myText = new Button();
        myText.Tag = counter;
        myText.Location = new Point(x2,y2);
        myText.Text = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
        this.Controls.Add(myText);
}
```

that is how I make the button at runtime.

Comment: Do you have many buttons to remove or only one? In case there are many, how do you want to choose which one to delete?

Comment: i have many buttons...iwant to mark the new button that i want to delete and then with keybord by prees delete it will delete..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove the last button you've added, you can use something like this:

```
//a list where you save all the buttons created
List<Button> buttonsAdded = new List<Button>();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button myText = new Button();
    myText.Tag = counter;
    myText.Location = new Point(x2,y2);
    myText.Text = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
    this.Controls.Add(myText);
    //add reference of the button to the list
    buttonsAdded.Insert(0, myText);

}

//atach this to a button removing the other buttons
private void removingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonsAdded.Count > 0)
    {
        Button buttonToRemove = buttonsAdded[0];
        buttonsAdded.Remove(buttonToRemove);
        this.Controls.Remove(buttonToRemove);
    }
}
```

This should allow you to remove as many buttons as you want by removing always the last one added from the existing ones.

**Update**

If you want to be able to hover a button with your mouse cursor and then delete it with *Delete* key, you can use this solution:

- set `KeyPreview` to *true*, so `Form` can receive key events occured in its controls
- add `buttonsAdded` list and modify `button2_Click` as in the first solution described in this answer
- create `KeyDown` event handler for your `Form` and add this code ot it:

  ```
  private void MySampleForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
      {
          //get control hovered with mouse
          Button buttonToRemove = (this.GetChildAtPoint(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) as Button);
          //if it's a Button, remove it from the form
          if (buttonsAdded.Contains(buttonToRemove))
              {
                  buttonsAdded.Remove(buttonToRemove);

                  this.Controls.Remove(buttonToRemove);
              }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: what i need to do to delete the new button?

Comment: In Visual Studio, in the designer of your form drag add a new button to the form, name it `removeButton` and attach `removingButton_Click` method to its `Click` event. After you compile and run the application, you'll get a removing button that allows you to remove a button from the ones that were added dynamically.

Comment: tnx so much that is really helps me  :)

Comment: you maby have the code to how can i delete the button that i want and not the last one that i made?

Comment: How do you want to select a button to be removed?

Comment: Check the updated answer that allows you to remove a `Button` hovered with mouse.

Comment: can you do that with out be hovered the button and do it just by mark the button and then press delete?

Comment: but its can delete any button on the form and i have some buttons that have to bee permannt that the function will not work on them :)

Comment: So use the list and check if the button found exists on this list (similarly to in the first answer). See the updated version of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use this.Controls.Remove(myText);

Comment: Are you trying to delete it with the action of another button? How are you trying to implement it?

Comment: no i want to mark the new button that imade and then by prees on delete on the keybord the button will delete...

Comment: see UnhandledException's answer. put the button reference into a class level variable, or since you are createing many buttons, have a dictionary of buttons as a class level variable and then you can get the dynamically created buttons' reference by name from the dictionary and then use the .Remove method

Answer (score 1):

```
public Button myText ; // keep public button to assign your new Button 

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        myText = new Button();
        myText.Tag = counter;
        myText.Location = new Point(x2,y2);
        myText.Text = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
        this.Controls.Add(myText);
}

private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(Button != null && this.Controls.Contains(myText))
      {
           this.Controls.Remove(myText);
           myText.Dispose();
      )
}
```

if you want to remove on delete key press you can use key down event as below

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
          if(Button != null && this.Controls.Contains(myText))
          {
               this.Controls.Remove(myText);
               myText.Dispose();
          )
    }
}
```

Comment: right click on your form and select properties and in property window go to events and find key down event. double click on that event. it will generate even for key down. put above `Window_KeyDown` event content in generated event code.