# C# remove dynamic created button

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue over here. I want to remove the dynamic created button by press the X button. 
The function will be user press X button, then press the button he/she want to delete, the button will be remove.

For now my program is able to create a new button but I do not know how to delete it, here is my coding, please help me , thanks very much!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class graphtest : Form
{
    public graphtest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Point Origin_Cursor;
    private Point Origin_Control;
    private bool BtnDragging = false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = new Button();
        b.Width = 54;
        b.Height = 58;
        b.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\prod01\Desktop\Mote.png");
        b.Text = "";
        b.Name = "button";
        //b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
        b.MouseUp += (s, e2) => { this.BtnDragging = false; };
        b.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseDown);
        b.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseMove);
        this.Controls.Add(b);



    }

    private void b_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button ct = sender as Button;
        ct.Capture = true;
        this.Origin_Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
        this.Origin_Control = ct.Location;
        this.BtnDragging = true;
    }

    private void b_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BtnDragging)
        {
            Button ct = sender as Button;
            ct.Left = this.Origin_Control.X - (this.Origin_Cursor.X - Cursor.Position.X);
            ct.Top = this.Origin_Control.Y - (this.Origin_Cursor.Y - Cursor.Position.Y);

        } 
    }

    private void graphtest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int ix = this.Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
        {
            if (this.Controls[ix] is Button) this.Controls[ix].Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: What I would do, put a flag bool when the "X" is press and set it to true, now when you click on an other button put a check in the event if the bool is set to true (which will mean that X was pressed earlier and the second click on the button means that you want to delete) find the button and remove it from the controls....

Comment: You could save the button into a variable and remove it from the `this.Controls` (don't forget the unregister the events.) or keep the newly created buttons in a `List<Button>` field

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that

```
//a list where you save all the buttons created
List<Button> buttonsAdded = new List<Button>();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button myText = new Button();
    myText.Tag = counter;
    myText.Location = new Point(x2,y2);
    myText.Text = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
    this.Controls.Add(myText);
    //add reference of the button to the list
    buttonsAdded.Insert(0, myText);

}

//atach this to a button removing the other buttons
private void removingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonsAdded.Count > 0)
    {
        Button buttonToRemove = buttonsAdded[0];
        buttonsAdded.Remove(buttonToRemove);
        this.Controls.Remove(buttonToRemove);
    }
}
```

Ref :- [how to delete a button run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262178/how-to-delete-a-button-run-time)